# Could not reshape broadcast array from one shape to given specification?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have created code to calculate cost function and stuck in the middle of the reshaping the array. following is my code.

```
def compute_logistic_cost(theta, x, y):
    m = y.size
    h = g(theta.T, np.dot (x))
    J = (1/m) * np.sum((-y * np.log(h(theta,X))) - ((1-y)*np.log(1-h(theta,x))))
    return J
```

and trying to generate the values for following values

```
theta = np.zeros( (3, 1) )
print(compute_logistic_cost(theta, X, y))


theta = np.array([[1.0],
                  [1.0],
                  [1.0]])

print(theta)
print(compute_logistic_cost(theta, X, y))

theta = np.array([[0.1],
                  [0.1],
                  [0.1]])
print(theta)
print(compute_logistic_cost(theta, X, y))
```

An error message is :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-36-634becb99ce9> in <module>
      1 X = np.ones( (4, m) )
    ----> 2 X[1:,:] = x.T # the second column contains the raw inputs
      3 Print(X.shape)

    ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (100,3) into shape (3,100)

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-37-f9e664174896> in <module>
      1 theta = np.zeros( (3, 1) )
    ----> 2 print(compute_logistic_cost(theta, X, y))
      3 
      4 
      5 theta = np.array([[1.0],

    <ipython-input-33-a3993443d55a> in compute_logistic_cost(theta, x, y)
      1 def compute_logistic_cost(theta, x, y):
      2     m = y.size
    ----> 3     h = g(theta.T, np.dot (x))
      4     J = (1/m) * np.sum((-y * np.log(h(theta,X))) - ((1-y)*np.log(1-h(theta,x))))
      5     return J

    NameError: name 'g' is not defined
```

I'm stuck in this problem since last couple of days and still going on. Need any suggestion

Comment: what is g ? if it is a function did you define it ?

Comment: g is a hypothesis function for logistic regression :

ℎ()=()

Comment: yes i know, but was it defined in your code ? because it seems it's not finding it

Comment: I have defined it as ------------            def sigmoid(z):
    new_val = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))
    return new_val

Comment: @nassim Can you please tell me - how to define g? I have used it as a predefine math function as I have imported math library.